# Unable to use debugger in Twilio Flex project with vscode

Tags: typescript, react-redux, twilio, source-maps, twilio-flex

I have a Twilio Plugin which I need to be able to debug in vscode.  I have followed the instructions found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/debugging-plugin-vs-code) to the letter but am still unable to debug.  The end result of following these instructions is that, when I click where I want to set a breakpoint, instead of red breakpoint being added, I see a hollow breakpoint.  Furthermore, when I hover my mouse over this hollow breakpoint, I see a message which says "Breakpoint set but not yet bound".

My project is a react project which has been set up to use typescript.  Any insight into what could be going wrong is greatly appreciated.

Currently, my launch.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/": "${webRoot}/"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I've not had a go with this myself, but a quick google shows you might need some more properties in your launch.json to handle TypeScript. Check this link to see what else you can try: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Because this hasn't gotten any responses, I think I'll post what I did for a workaround... I've been able to debug my code using the developer console in chrome by inserting the keyword "debugger" in my code.  Then, with my browser's dev tools open, I will do an action that I know will trigger the code with the "debugger" line to be run.

The above isn't the answer I was looking for when I initially posted my question, but doing these steps has been my workaround for the issues I was having.  I truly hope this helps someone.